# FoxPro database comes up with an "invalid seek offset" error when using the dbf file

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have a problem with the FoxPro database. When  I am using dbf file it comes with an error saying "Invalid seek offset". I have attached a screenshot below. Can anyone help me to sort out my problem?[image: Invalid seek offset]

Comment: If you have a backup, you can try loading from there.  Otherwise, you are screwed.  The last release was in 2007 and support was ended in 2015.

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, Thank you for taking time to reply. Yes, it is an outdated database, but there are some important data that I need in the FoxPro dbf file. I have no idea why that error popped out. I do have not much knowledge about FoxPro. As you said how can use backup here? Previously I use this dbf file, but now when I am trying it popped out the above error.

Comment: Try moving that table to another place like c:\temp. Also use:
use ('transact') note the parentheses and quotes. transaction is a reserved word really (and VFP might use only 4 or more letters).

Comment: @TimRoberts, VFP still works wonderfully well. MS has never really supported it. Does MS do support any of its products anyway? How many times do you remember you got support from MS?

Comment: Is on a network?  The only time I've gotten it was when there was some corruption along the network system. Can you physically copy the transact.dbf (and cdx) to another drive and try to open it there? Now if it's in a database container, you'll need to grab everything.

Comment: @CetinBasoz -- Absolutely, Microsoft supports its products.  If you pay for support, as businesses often do, you get people who dig in to your questions and get answers.  I've talked to developers many times.

Comment: _"I've talked to developers many times"_ @TimRoberts , you are probably kidding? Please ask your developers what MS support would have done with a damaged data file and a missing backup before VFP support ended

Comment: Hi @CetinBasoz, thank you for your reply. As you said i'll move it another place and try it. I'll let you know after trying.

Comment: Hi @HankWilson, Thank you for taking time to reply. The dbf file is in a VM. I was trying it in VM. As you asked yes it is in a database container. I'll move all files to different location, then check and let you knwo.

Comment: @TimRoberts, you are surely kidding. Microsoft cannot even support its own forums let alone products.

Comment: Hi @CetinBasoz, I moved the transact dbf file to c drive and tried it. But same error popped out in there. So do you have any idea to sort out this problem ?

Comment: Hi @HankWilson, I moved the transact dbf file to c drive and tried it. But same error popped out in there. So do you have any idea to sort out this problem ?

Comment: Hi @CetinBasoz, After the above error (Invalid seek offset) i am getting error "File is in use".

Comment: Then it is in use in elsewhere. You might select its workspace by using its alias: select ('aliasName').